# How to integrate raw data from Matomo to Tableau

Tags: database, analytics, tableau-api, matomo

I am using Matomo on prem to collect data from apps/websites. To vizualize/analyze data I would like to use Tableau.

Is it possible to import data from Matomo db to Tableau?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with Tableau is a mess without creating a connector. Playing with raw data is not just about one sql queries but many. I reached the best results with Redash not Tableau with the import of json request from the api.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use tableau...did you try to connect directly to mySQL DB from matomo server? i hope it is possible but didn't try yet.